# strange system call semantics on nfs mount

Tags: c, linux, file, nfs

I am writing a little test program for the open() function in C @ open SuSE leap 42.2 x64.

Unfortunately the file being created gets -rwxrwxrwx permissions, although I hand over 0644 to the open() function after executing **umask(0);**

Could anyone please tell me, what I am doing wrong?
(I got the example code from an open book ([link](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/linux_unix_programmierung/Kap02-002.htm#RxxKap02002040000CC1F0231D2)).

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /* Zugriffsrechte 644 */
    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH;

    const char *new_file;
    int file_descriptor;
    /* Alle Zugriffsrechte der Einschraenkungsmaske erlauben */
    umask(0);
    /* Argument 2 der cmd line auswerten */
    if (argv[1] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s datei_zum_oeffnen\n", *argv);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    new_file = argv[1];
    file_descriptor = open(new_file, O_WRONLY|O_EXCL|O_CREAT, 0644);
    /* or var mode instead of (0644) */
    if (file_descriptor == -1) {
        perror("Fehler bei open ");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Either way - handing over 0644 or the variable "mode" as open()'s third argument do not work as expected and the result when executing the program (as normal user) and handing in a filename is: -rwxrwxrwx and moreover: the file belongs to root:root instead of the executing user?!

What will I have to change?

Comment: The mention of root etc suggests that the file you're looking at is not the one the program creates.  If you're not running as root, it is very unlikely (essentially impossible) for your program to create the root-owned file.  Is the file empty?  If you remove it before you run the program and you verify that it has gone, does it reappear after the program is run?  If you specify a different name, do you get the same result?  If you specify `/tmp/test.file` do you see the problem?  What are the permissions on the executable?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This behavior is a bit strange - i execute the program as normal user and it creates a file belonging to root, but with all rights to world. - so I was able to delete it. The file is empty and 0 bytes - it's only created, so that is correct I think. But - copying the executable to my home dir - changes this behavior, making the whole thing work as intended. - See answer below.

Comment: Related: [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved.**

The failure was compiling it using NetBeans 8.2.
The folders and files created by NetBeans belong to root - creating the same .c-file in my home dir and compiling it there worked perfectly.

**Added:**
NetBeans is **not** running as root.
The folder which my **workspace** was created in is a **NTFS drive**, mounted during boot with user-access - but the whole drive belongs to root in the first place. I am 99% convinced that this is what led me to wrong assumptions about NetBeans creating folders and files with wrong permissions.

Comment: Very curious.  If NetBeans runs as root, I will never use it.  It isn't safe to experiment as root.  I did wonder if an IDE was part of the trouble, but I didn't want cast aspersions unnecessarily.

Comment: @user268396: Good.  How could it be messed up so that it runs as root?  I'm assuming that it isn't being run as `sudo netbeans` or something similar, though maybe that isn't a safe assumption.  (I'm not a fan of IDEs, so I don't know from my own experience.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it doesn't run as root by default. To start it you invoke (directly or indirectly via a `.desktop` file) a shell script which starts up a Java application...  It's a Java Swing app, so no need to run as root at all.

Comment: Why are all the folders created by netbeans owned by root then? I downloaded, installed and run NetBeans as a normal user and never get asked for root password... how come!?

Comment: @user268396: With luck, Ben will notice this and explain what he does to end up with NetBeans running as root.  Meanwhile, I am reassured that NetBeans (normally) runs as the user who invokes it with no elevated privileges.

Comment: I did and answered including a pic - I have no clue, I do not run anything as root regarding netbeans.

Comment: Self-answers are good for SO, thanks. Unfortunately, there are two upvotes that I didn't give you here because your question and answer is not detailed enough to help the next person. In particular, it you don't describe why anything was happening as root. If you do improve this, you'll probably get more than my upvotes. It is a good question at core. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @msw: I can't explain this at this point. I did download, install and run NEtBeans as a normal user and I simply do not know why NB creates root-owned files and folders when clicking on compile - but while writing this sentence I have an idea: the folder which my workspace was created in is a NTFS drive, mounted during boot with user-access - but the whle drive seems to belong to root therefore - I guess this COULD be the reason for myself thinking it was NetBeans' fault. I will add this to my answer. Greets

Comment: I'm glad you tracked down the system configuration fault. Have an upvote or two.